# In Kibana how can you sum nested fields and then bucket for each document?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, kibana

We have multiple nested fields which need to be summed and then graphed almost as if it were a value of the parent document (using scripted fields is not an ideal solution for us).

Given the example index mapping:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "build_name": { "type": "keyword" },
        "start_ms": { "type": "date" },
        "projects": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "project_duration_ms": { type": "long" },
            "project_name": { "type": "keyword" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example doc._source:

```
{
  "build_name": "example_build_1",
  "start_ms": "1611252094540",
  "projects": [
    { "project_duration_ms": "19381", project_name": "example_project_1" },
    { "project_duration_ms": "2081", "project_name": "example_project_2" }
  ]
},
{
  "build_name": "example_build_2",
  "start_ms": "1611252097638",
  "projects": [
    { "project_duration_ms": "21546", project_name": "example_project_1" },
    { "project_duration_ms": "2354", "project_name": "example_project_2" }
  ]
}
```

It would be ideal to get a aggregation something like:

```
....
  "aggregations" : {
    "builds" : {
      "total_durations" : {
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key": "example_build_1",
            "start_ms": "1611252094540",
            "total_duration": "21462"
          },
          {
            "key": "example_build_2",
            "start_ms": "1611252097638",
            "total_duration": "23900"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No scripted fields necessary. This [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) [sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) should do the trick:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "builds": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "build_name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_durations_parent": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "projects"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_durations": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "projects.project_duration_ms"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your use case is a great candidate for employing the [`copy_to` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) which'll put the build durations into one top-level list of longs so that the `nested` query won't be required when we're summing them up.

Adjust the mapping like so:

```
"properties": {
  "build_name": { "type": "keyword" },
  "start_ms": { "type": "date" },
  "total_duration_ms": { "type": "long" },    <--
  "projects": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "project_duration_ms": {
        "type": "long",
        "copy_to": "total_duration_ms"        <--
      },
      "project_name": { "type": "keyword" }
    }
  }
}
```

After reindexing (which is required due to the newly added field), the above query gets simplified to:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "builds": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "build_name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_durations": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "total_duration_ms"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We also have a `build_number` field which uniquely identifies each document - I realized that I could aggregate on that field and end up with a summation of the durations for each build based on that. This involved changing the first `agg` to `"field": "build_number"`. Thanks for the help

Comment: You got it. Yup -- anything that's a `keyword` or a number can be aggregated right away inside of a `terms` agg.

Comment: Hey btw I'm writing an elasticsearch handbook full of examples like this, plus other non-trivial, real-world use cases. You can [let me know](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) what you'd like to see in there and I'll let you know when it's out!

Comment: Ha, actually now I need to graph this output - is that possible? I've posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835870/in-kabana-can-you-create-a-line-chart-from-a-custom-aggregation

Comment: Not sure if it's possible w/ the nested field but when it's on the same level, it should work just fine!

Comment: Is it possible if I use your second suggestion? Can you sum the list and then graph that?

Comment: Yes -- the 2nd suggestion does just that. Here is is visualized in a kibana line chart: https://prnt.sc/xicfg1